# Spark Java How to get the sum of the byte length all the rows of a column?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need to read a large number of avro files, filter them by some criteria, then I need to get the length of each column in a row and finally I want to get the sum of all the values in this new column

The code I've written doesn't seem to be working. It worked once and did some logging and stopped working after that. Also, when printing, `myLength` is turning out to be zero, which is `not` possible

I'll be very grateful if you guys could give me some pointers, help

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static java.util.logging.Level.INFO;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.length;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.LongType;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes.StringType;

Dataset<Row> loadedFiles =
        platformContext
                .getSparkSession()
                .sqlContext()
                .read()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
                .load(files);

Dataset<Row> myFilteredFiles = loadedFiles
        .filter(col("value").contains("regex"))
        .filter(col("value".isNotNull());

long myCount = myFilteredFiles.count();

long myLength = myCount <= 0L ? 0L : myFilteredFiles
        .withColumn("value_length", length(col("value")))
        .agg(sum(col("value_length")).cast(LongType))
        .first()
        .getLong(0);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("myCount=").append(myCount).append(" myLength=").appendmyLength);
LOGGER.log(INFO, sb.toString());
```